# Publishing a windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, publish, marketplace

I tried to find on the internet if there is a cost to publish your app in Windows Phone Market.
I just created an app and I wish to make it available as beta for anyone.
I know that it would be better to post this kind of questions on Windows Phone Stack, but in that site no one answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay to have a developer account, which as an individual in the UK costs £12. Once registered, there is no extra cost to submit an app. There are more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863494.aspx